# Panoramaview styling issue

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I want to format the standard PanoramaApp, when selecting new project from visual studio, but am having trouble doing so.

I want to edit "Third Item" to show the borders with 2 subheadings neatly which will later be used in databindings, however I am not sure how to do that? I have tried playing around with the formatting of listbox / longlistselector but cannot seem to get my formatting and items template to work.

So now I am trying to create a grid which will contain all the different pics with subheadings, however I don't think this is the correct way of doing it

```
 <phone:PanoramaItem Header="third item" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Heading1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="167"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Heading2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,0,0" />
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        <Border Grid.Column="3" Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the sample:

```
<Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
```

With the following

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Heading1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="167"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Heading2" Margin="12,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: hi, thanx for the reply, this is kind of what I need, but the 2 headings are now over the border, I need it to be specifically beneath the different blocks, but without setting specific positions